# Disable WKActionSheet on WKWebView

Tags: uiactionsheet, wkwebview

I'm migrating an iOS app form UIWebView to WKWebView. So far so good... In the previous app I disabled long press and implemented a custom long press (to do custom handling of links), however I can't get this working in the WKWebView

I've tried the following:

```
- (void)webView:(WKWebView *)wkWebView didFinishNavigation:(WKNavigation *)navigation {
    [wkWebView evaluateJavaScript:@"document.body.style.webkitTouchCallout='none';" completionHandler:nil];
}
```

I've checked and that line gets executed, the response of the call is @"None"

But it responds with:
Warning: Attempt to present  on  whose view is not in the window hierarchy!

Any ideas?
**SOLUTION:**
Inject javascript into wkwebview now works!

```
[self.wkWebView evaluateJavaScript:@"document.body.style.webkitTouchCallout='none';" completionHandler:nil];
```

Comment: Bug reported:
https://devforums.apple.com/message/1024729#1024729

Comment: You stated in your "edit" you have solved it. Would be interesting to know how, it was not clear for me. Any hints?

Comment: Sorry for bad description but wasn't sure what really happened.

Comment: I really need an answer to this... How? Did Apple approve?

Comment: Not sure what happened, but apple did approve

Comment: Can you explain how did you solve this problem. thx. All I am trying to have cut.copy, paste menu on long press

Comment: @DanielÅkesson can you provide an answer for how to present a custom hyperlink handler for a wkwebview with associated custom action sheet? I would love to figure it out and upvote the answer.

Comment: Hi Daniel, as asked above by other people, could you please provide the solution you've found ? It looks like you don't want to share it; it's kind of weird to ask for some help to a community but not be willing to help that community back.

Comment: The javascript injection works for me in later versions. I updated the solution

Comment: does this work on latest iOS versions?

Answer (score 18):

This is the solution in Swift 3.0:

```
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
     webView.evaluateJavaScript("document.body.style.webkitTouchCallout='none';")
}
```

Answer (score 14):

```
myWkWebView.allowsLinkPreview = false
```

Comment: Just what I've looked for! Thanks! On iOS 13 images in WKWebView become available to preview in a manner of 3D touch preview but even on non-3D touch capable devices. Just with long press.

Comment: This is perfect! It works just how I want it to. +1

Answer (score 4):

I haven't verified it, but it looks like you can also use CSS to disable this functionality:

```
-webkit-touch-callout: none;
```

Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/-webkit-touch-callout

Comment: This is works for me iOS 12.4 and Swift 5
Work with this link 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/33126467/4593553