# Insert CSS into loaded HTML in UIWebView / WKWebView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview, wkwebview

I am successfully able to get HTML content and display into my UIWebView.

But want to customize the content by adding an external CSS file.  I can only change the size of text and font.  I tried every possible solution to make changes but it does not work - it shows no changes.

Below is my code

```
HTMLNode* body = [parser body];
HTMLNode* mainContentNode = [body  findChildWithAttribute:@"id" matchingName:@"main_content" allowPartial:NO];
NSString *pageContent = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", cssString, contentHtml];
        [webView loadHTMLString:pageContent baseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.example.org"]];

-(void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView1{
    int fontSize = 50;
    NSString *font = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].style.webkitTextSizeAdjust= '%d%%'", fontSize];
    NSString *fontString = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"document.getElementById('body').style.fontFamily=\"helvetica\""];

    [webView1 stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:fontString];
    [webView1 stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:font];
}
```

Please help me get the css stylesheet in my view.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
    NSString *cssString = @"body { font-family: Helvetica; font-size: 50px }"; // 1
    NSString *javascriptString = @"var style = document.createElement('style'); style.innerHTML = '%@'; document.head.appendChild(style)"; // 2
    NSString *javascriptWithCSSString = [NSString stringWithFormat:javascriptString, cssString]; // 3
    [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:javascriptWithCSSString]; // 4
}
```

What this code does:

// 1 : Define a string that contains all the CSS declarations

// 2 : Define a javascript string that creates a new `<style>` HTML DOM element and inserts the CSS declarations into it. Actually the inserting is done in the next step, right now there is only the `%@` placeholder. I did this to prevent the line from becoming too long, but step 2 and 3 could be done together.

// 3 : Combine the 2 strings

// 4 : Execute the javascript in the UIWebView

For this to work, your HTML has to have a `<head></head>` element.

**EDIT:**

You can also load the css string from a local css file (named "styles.css" in this case). Just replace step //1 with the following:

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"styles" ofType:@"css"];
NSString *cssString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:path encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
```

As another option you can just inject a `<link>` element to the `<head>` that loads the CSS file:

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"styles" ofType:@"css"];
    NSString *javascriptString = @"var link = document.createElement('link'); link.href = '%@'; link.rel = 'stylesheet'; document.head.appendChild(link)";
    NSString *javascriptWithPathString = [NSString stringWithFormat:javascriptString, path];
    [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:javascriptWithPathString];
}
```

This solution works best for large CSS files. Unfortunately it does not work with remote HTML files. You can only use this when you want to insert CSS into HTML that you have downloaded to your app.

**UPDATE: WKWebView / Swift 3.x**

When you are working with a `WKWebView` injecting a `<link>` element does not work because of `WKWebView`'s security settings.

You can still inject the css as a string. Either create the CSS string in your code `//1` or put it in a local file `//2`. Just be aware that with WKWebView you have to do the injection in `WKNavigationDelegate`'s `webView(_:didFinish:)` method:

```
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
    insertCSSString(into: webView) // 1
    // OR
    insertContentsOfCSSFile(into: webView) // 2
}

func insertCSSString(into webView: WKWebView) {
    let cssString = "body { font-size: 50px; color: #f00 }"
    let jsString = "var style = document.createElement('style'); style.innerHTML = '\(cssString)'; document.head.appendChild(style);"
    webView.evaluateJavaScript(jsString, completionHandler: nil)
}

func insertContentsOfCSSFile(into webView: WKWebView) {
    guard let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "styles", ofType: "css") else { return }
    let cssString = try! String(contentsOfFile: path).trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines)
    let jsString = "var style = document.createElement('style'); style.innerHTML = '\(cssString)'; document.head.appendChild(style);"
    webView.evaluateJavaScript(jsString, completionHandler: nil)
}
```

Comment: Sorry for my late reply :(
Could you explain what this line means ?
NSString *javascriptString = @"var style = document.createElement('style'); style.innerHTML = '%@'; document.head.appendChild(style)";
It does not work for me ..!

Comment: Hi Cole, I've updated my answer with some explanations on what the code does.

Comment: Hi,
Thanks for making me understand your code !! 
But its not working.. i have created separate css file for the app.

Comment: Could you help me if i use a local css file. How to call in webViewDidFinishLoad: ? I tried few methods online and it does not work

Comment: Sure, you can load the contents of a local CSS file into `cssString` and inject it into the HTML with the same method. See my edited answer

Comment: I did same thing and it did not worked. The layout is same :(

Comment: What HTML page are you loading? Can you post the URL or the HMTL file if it's a local file? Also please show me the CSS you are trying to inject.

Comment: Sorry i cannot share my URL link on public site but can share css file. If you like i can send it directly to your mail and you can check yourself ?

Comment: send, please check !!

Comment: That's quite a big CSS file. It is better if you insert it into the HTML via a `<link>` element. See updated answer. Also your file had encoding problem. I send you a clean version of your file via mail

Comment: Thanks for fixing it. I send you a personal message and let me know your thoughts.  I am going to accept your answer.

Comment: @joern is it possible with WKWebView?  I'm not getting success into it . . .

Comment: @NamanVaishnav The method using a `<link>` element does not work with `WKWebView`. But you can still inject a CSS String. Please see my updated answer.

Comment: This code works for me but only till iOS 10.2 , it's not working in iOS 10.3. Anyone is facing same issue ? or help me ?

Comment: @joern how to do it, if my html is having div element not head?

Comment: Do you load your HTML from a server or do you have it locally as a String?

Comment: I get it from server @joern

Comment: @Mansuu.... You can load the HTML into a String (`String(contentsOf: URL)`), add the style tag with the CSS to that String and then load the WebView with that String (using `loadHTMLString(_:baseURL:)`). Just make sure to load the HTML into the String asynchronously to avoid blocking the UI.

Comment: @joern I am trying to add css from external file added in to bundle resource(build phase) and adding like                                                      let mainbundle = Bundle.main.bundlePath
            let bundleURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: mainbundle)
            postTitleWebView.isHidden=false
            postTitleWebView.loadHTMLString(title!, baseURL:bundleURL as URL)                       but it not working

Comment: @joern I also tried the same as You suggested in this answer, but still not working

Comment: @Mansuu.... Try putting the contents of the CSS file (as a String) into your HTML string. Don't forget to embed the CSS into a Style element `<style type="text/css">YOUR CSS</style>`

Comment: @joern so do I need to enclose my css content within style tag in css file?

Comment: @Mansuu.... Yes. You want 1 String containing the HTML AND the CSS (enclosed in a style element). Don't use an external file for the css.

Comment: @joern But I get html from server and it may have different html tags every time so how can I make single string using my html and css?

Comment: @Mansuu.... please check my above comment where I explain how to load the HTML into a String etc. It doesn't  matter if the server HTML changes. Just make 1 String by adding the CSS String to the HTML String. I am currently on the road and only have my phone on me so I cannot provide you with more detail. I hope you figure it out. Otherwise maybe open a new question for your problem if you have the feeling that this answer doesn't solve your problem.

Comment: @joern Hi have tried your code but javascript is not working in WKWebview.

I want to load css and js after WKWebview finish load.

Comment: @EktaPadaliya This question is only about inserting CSS into a WebView, but have a look at this answer regarding the injection of JS into a WKWebView: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40730365/4891259

Comment: @joern : can you please answer my question ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46321254/how-to-load-css-file-in-uiwebview

Comment: @Nirav Have you tried the insertContentsOfCSSFile() approach in my answer? It should work for your case.

Comment: I think webView:didFinish:navigation: isn't the best inject time.

Comment: It works. But I have to wrap cssString into **single** line. The multi-line by `"""` doesn't work.

Comment: @AechoLiu You can use a multi-line `"""` string if you surround the `style.innerHTML = '\(cssStyle)'` with back ticks `\``. So that part of code would then be `style.innerHTML = \`\(cssStyle)\`;`. This makes `\(cssStyle)` a multiline Javascript string matching the Swift multi-line string.

Comment: Inserting `<link>` also works in WKWebView if you set wkWebView to use: `wkWebView.loadHTMLString(html, baseURL: Bundle.main.resourceURL)`

Answer (score 31):

Since `UIWebView` is deprecated in iOS 12, I'll only answer for `WKWebView`.
I've implemented CSS loading like it was described in the accepted answer. The problem was that sometimes the transition from HTML with no CSS applied to HTML with CSS was visible.
I think a better approach is to use the `WKUserScript` to inject the CSS like this:

```
lazy var webView: WKWebView = {
    guard let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "style", ofType: "css") else {
        return WKWebView()
    }

    let cssString = try! String(contentsOfFile: path).components(separatedBy: .newlines).joined()
    let source = """
      var style = document.createElement('style');
      style.innerHTML = '\(cssString)';
      document.head.appendChild(style);
    """

    let userScript = WKUserScript(source: source,
                                  injectionTime: .atDocumentEnd,
                                  forMainFrameOnly: true)

    let userContentController = WKUserContentController()
    userContentController.addUserScript(userScript)

    let configuration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
    configuration.userContentController = userContentController

    let webView = WKWebView(frame: .zero,
                            configuration: configuration)
    return webView
}()
```

You can read more about this approach in this [blog post](https://www.amerhukic.com/determining-the-content-size-of-a-wkwebview).

Comment: I had the same issue. The transition was visible. It worked like charm. Thank you!!

Comment: This works perfect. The result html doesn't blink when css injected.

Comment: This is a way to do it on iOS 12, I've been struggling with this for so long. Many thanx!

Comment: Excellent! Glad I found this comment. No glitches with this solution.

Comment: The other solution doesn't work for me, but this does.

Comment: Remember to set `configuration.suppressesIncrementalRendering = true` to avoid seen the transition while the page is still loading.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of applying css with style tag it's better to apply it with the link tag:

```
func insertContentsOfCSSFile2(into webView: WKWebView) {
    guard let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "resource", ofType: "css") else { return }                
    let csFile = "var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];var link = document.createElement('link'); link.rel = 'stylesheet';link.type = 'text/css';link.href = '\(path)';link.media = 'all';head.appendChild(link);"

    webView.evaluateJavaScript(csFile) {(result, error) in
        if let error = error {
            print(error)
        }
    }
}
```

I have tested it. 
it is working fine.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add this header before apple style to HTML

```
let fontName = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 17.0).fontName
    let htmlContent = """
    <header>
    <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no'>
    </header>
    <style type='text/css'>
    img{max-height: 100%; min-height: 100%; height:auto; max-width: 100%; width:auto;margin-bottom:5px;}
    p{text-align:left|right|center; line-height: 180%; font-family: '\(fontName)'; font-size: 17px;}
    iframe{width:100%; height:250px;}
    </style> \(html)
    """
    webView.loadHTMLString(htmlContent, baseURL: Bundle.main.bundleURL)
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried Amer Hukic answer. But did not work just the way it is. I added below code between my html head tags.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
```

Answer (score 0):

See @joern's accepted answer for more complete details. I'm adding this answer because I ran into a weird edge case. My particular use case needed to add styling to a `div` with a `class="dialog"`. For some reason styling using `.dialog` and `div` weren't working though other types of styling were working. In the end I used the following to set the width of the `dialog`

```
let width = Int(webView.bounds.width)
let script = "document.getElementsByClassName(\"dialog\")[0].style.width = \"\(width)px\""
webView.evaluateJavaScript(script)
```