# Style HTML select tag on ios/safari/iPhone

Tags: html, ios, css, iphone, safari

I have three dropdown lists (three `<select>` elements). I styled them with the css:

```
.dropdown{
    font-size: 20px;
    background: white;
    border:none;
    position: relative;
}
```

In chrome they look perfectly fine. However when I test the site on my iPhone 6s (ios 10.2.1) on Safari the result is a bit different as shown in the image:
[image]

As you can see there's that `gradient` in `background` and near the arrow the `background` is `black`.

> How can I style the `<select>` elements so I would have background `white` on ios either?

Comment: You can use http://stackoverflow.com/a/33126467/4042468 and set css to your HTML.

Comment: @kerry I don't understand how would that help me. Can you explain your workaround?

Comment: apologies, misread your question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As Stian Martinsen [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42158112/6162549) `-webkit-appearance: none;` disable default styling of `<select>` tag, but it also hides the arrow. So I find a workaround with this code:

```css
.dropdown{
   font-size: 20px;
   background: white;
   border:none;
   position: relative;
   -webkit-appearance: none;
        padding-right: 10px;
  }
  .dropdown:focus{
   outline: none;
  }
  .plain-selector{
   margin: 0 3px;
  }
  .plain-selector::after{
   content: "";
     position: absolute;
     z-index: 2;
     bottom: 30%;
     margin-top: -3px;
     height: 0;
     width: 0;
     right: 0;
     border-top: 6px solid black;
     border-left: 6px solid transparent;
     border-right: 6px solid transparent;
     pointer-events: none;
  }
  .plain-selector::before{
   content: "";
     position: absolute;
     z-index: 2;
     top: 30%;
     margin-top: -3px;
     height: 0;
     width: 0;
     right: 0;
     border-bottom: 6px solid black;
     border-left: 6px solid transparent;
     border-right: 6px solid transparent;
     pointer-events: none;
  }
  .out-selector{
   position: relative;
  }
     .outter-selection{
      width: 100%;
     }
     .selection{
    display: block;
  margin: auto;
  border-radius: 50px;
  background: white;
  padding: 5px;
  max-width: 360px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 90%;
  position: relative;
 }
body{
   margin-top: 4em;
   background: #2f2f2f;
   color: white;
   font-size: 23px;
  }
```

```html
<div class="outter-selection">
 <div class="selection">
  <span class="out-selector"><span class="plain-selector"><select class="dropdown">
   <option value="1" selected="selected">select 1</option>
   <option value="2">select 2</option>
   <option value="3">select 3</option>
   <option value="4">select 4</option>
  </select></span></span>
  <span class="out-selector"><span class="plain-selector"><select class="dropdown">
            <option value="1" selected="selected">1</option>
   <option value="2">2</option>
   <option value="3">3</option>
   <option value="4">4</option>
          </select></span></span>
  <span class="out-selector"><span class="plain-selector"><select class="dropdown">
            <option value="1" selected="selected">1</option>
   <option value="2">2</option>
   <option value="3">3</option>
   <option value="4">4</option>
          </select></span></span>
  </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: thanks, `webkit-appearance` even helps with resizing it how I want - so I can make whole wrapper clickable regardless of its dimensions

Comment: This answer to another question worked for me, using a lot less CSS. https://stackoverflow.com/a/63227642/498949

Comment: I have not found this solution applicable for attached "select" control design https://ibb.co/R7KMyBP.

Answer (score 36):

Try adding this CSS to disable Ios' default styling:

```
-webkit-appearance: none;
```

This will also work on other elements that get special styling, like input[type=search].

Comment: In addition to this answer, please also take note `<select>` elements are not fully style-able. A search on the matter will provide quite a few results. The only full-proof workaround is to use a plugin that replaces the `<select>`s with other `html` elements. Again, you have multiple options.

Comment: @StianMartinsen, that will also hide the arrow which is not what I wanted. So is there a workaround to replace the arrow?

Comment: Yes, making -webkit-appearance: none; hides dropdown arrow, I could not have find the solution for it so far as well.