# CSS: -webkit-appearance: menulist Dropdown (Select tag), how to give padding to the arrow?

Tags: css, google-chrome, webkit

I have this html for a select tag:

```
<div>
   <label> Country </label> 
   <span>
      <select>
         <option value=""></option>
         ...
      </select>
   </span>
</div>
```

it's relevant CSS is this:

```
select {
    -webkit-appearance: menulist;
}
label {
    margin-left: 1rem;
}
```

And here is what it looks like:

[image: country dropdown]

See how the dropdown arrow has no space  with the right border of the select element?

That's what I'm trying to style.

So is there a CSS selector that can help me do this?
Or should I just go ahead and customize it all the way using `content: "someglyph"`?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I always hide the arrow and add an .svg arrow as a background. Not a very nice solution but it works cross browser. Selects are a real pain in the web.

Comment: I'll leave the question open a little more to see if someone knows a better way to do it, but for now what I did was removing the border and bg color from the <select> and applied those to the the wrapper <span>, and by adding `padding-right: 1rem;` I could achieve what I wanted. Still, I agree with @MaZoli, the best cross browser option is to hide the arrow and use an icon or a backgorund

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way to solve this is to apply this little CSS:

```
select {
      appearance: none;
      background-color: transparent;
      background-image: url(arrow.svg);
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-position: right;
      background-size: 30px;
}
```

and as @mazoli mentioned, this solution is cross browser.

Comment: No need to bring your own svg, here's a middle-gray one that will probably work just fine: `background-image: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB2aWV3Qm94PSIwIDAgMTAwMCAxMDAwIiB4bWxucz0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMjAwMC9zdmciPg0KICA8cGF0aCBmaWxsPSJncmF5IiBkPSJNMTAsMjMyLjdsNDkwLDUzNC41bDQ5MC01MzQuNUgxMHoiIC8+DQo8L3N2Zz4=);`