# Hide the share option in context menu on text selection in QLPreviewController

Tags: ios, qlpreviewcontroller

I'm using sample code from 
[https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/DocInteraction/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010052]

Run the above code, open the .txt file, long press on any text, the text gets selected and you will see a context menu with options "copy/look up/share etc" as in the picture[image]

I do not want to show the "Share" option in this context menu. I tried to remove the long press completely etc, but nothing seems to work.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: That's a common, system-wide iOS feature, and isn't meant to be disabled or hidden.

Comment: For security reasons in our app, I'm trying to do that! When you open pdf document, you do not see the share button. I need something similar!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of QLPreviewController, used WKWebview to preview docs. Used [Insert CSS into loaded HTML in UIWebView / WKWebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33123093/insert-css-into-loaded-html-in-uiwebview-wkwebview) to disable user interaction.