# ios load css in a webview

Tags: html, ios, css, uiwebview

**I have:** a big **html string** of an article which I load in a wkWebView like that:

```
[[self webView]loadHTMLString:htmlStr baseURL:nil];
```

**I need to** load css from web page where this article is located.

Article located here: https://vivreathenes.com/visiter-athenes-en-famille-le-nouveau-musee-de-l-enfant.html

I have no idea how I can do this so any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I believe this is a duplicate of this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33123093/insert-css-into-loaded-html-in-uiwebview-wkwebview

Comment: doesnt work for me

Comment: Have you tried: `[[self webView]loadHTMLString:htmlStr baseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://vivreathenes.com/"]];` ? (I'm assuming your *"big html string"* contains the css hrefs)

Comment: yes I did doesn't change anything

Comment: OK - where are you getting your "big html string"? And does that string have the `<link rel='stylesheet'` links in it?

Comment: I get it from here: https://vivreathenes.com/wp-json/wp/v2/post-data/29457 No it doesn't have the string.

Comment: OK - are you hoping to replicate the page as seen via your Article link? Or do you just want the font  styles / colors?

Comment: I have an article from the back end and I want to set it (only article nothing more) in a WkWebView exactly as this article looks in a webPage.

Comment: The "post" html string you are getting doesn't have any css definitions in it. To get it to display anything like it looks when you go to that page, you'll have to get the css from somewhere else.