# WKWebView: How to insert text to HTML when loading local html

Tags: html, ios, wkwebview

When using a WKWebView to load local HTML files (not on-line resource), I need pass some variable in. The Title index exactly ,which is determined by the tableView indexpath of the last page, as the following image.

[image: img]

I have seem the css question: [Insert CSS into loaded HTML in UIWebView / WKWebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33123093/insert-css-into-loaded-html-in-uiwebview-wkwebview)

Is there some way else to handle?

Like Java's template syntax or Python's Jinja2 syntax.

Here is the html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <h3>
            如何查询我购买的订单？
        </h3>
        <p>您好，请微信关注“中通创客”，点击右下角“我的”，选择“订单查询”查询订单信息。
        </p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

The content of `<h3>` tag to insert

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have full control over the HTML files you could insert a placeholder where you want to insert your value:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
                <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
                    <title>Document</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <h3>
                @@index@@ 如何查询我购买的订单？
            </h3>
            <p>您好，请微信关注“中通创客”，点击右下角“我的”，选择“订单查询”查询订单信息。
            </p>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Then you can load the HTML content into a `String` and replace the placeholder with your value before loading the HTML into the `WKWebView`:

```
if let filepath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "content", ofType: "html") {
    do {
        let rawHtmlString = try String(contentsOfFile: filepath)
        let htmlString = rawHtmlString.replacingOccurrences(of: "@@index@@", with: "17.")
        webView.loadHTMLString(htmlString, baseURL: nil)
    } catch {
        // contents could not be loaded
    }
}
```

If you cannot insert a placeholder and have to use the HTML files as they are you could insert your value like this:

```
if let filepath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "content", ofType: "html") {
    do {
        let rawHtmlString = try String(contentsOfFile: filepath)

        // get the ranges of the h3 tags
        if let h3OpeningTagRange = rawHtmlString.range(of: "<h3>"), let h3ClosingTagRange = rawHtmlString.range(of: "</h3>") {

            // get the text inbetween the h3 tags
            let h3Content = rawHtmlString[h3OpeningTagRange.upperBound..<h3ClosingTagRange.lowerBound]

            // build the new html string
            let htmlString =
                // everything until and including the <h3> tag
                rawHtmlString[...h3OpeningTagRange.upperBound]
                // the value you want to insert
                + "17. "
                // the text inbetween the h3 tags
                + h3Content
                // the rest of the hmtl including the </h3> tag
                + rawHtmlString[h3ClosingTagRange.lowerBound...]

            webView.loadHTMLString(String(htmlString), baseURL: nil)
        }
    } catch {
        // contents could not be loaded
    }
}
```

This gets the range of the opening `<h3>` tag and the range of the closing `</h3>` tag and constructs the HTML string using those ranges.

This is not a very robust way of doing this, but it might be an easy solution for your special case.

Answer (score 1):

Try appending following javascript to your HTML

```
"""
<script>
    window.addEventListener('load', function () {    
        var h3Node = document.getElementsByTagName('h3')[0];
        h3Node.innerHTML = "\(Your_desired_string_to_show)" + h3Node.innerHTML
    });

</script>
"""
```

## Sample Output

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <h3>
            如何查询我购买的订单？
        </h3>
        <p>您好，请微信关注“中通创客”，点击右下角“我的”，选择“订单查询”查询订单信息。
        </p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>

<script>
    window.addEventListener("load", function () {    
        var h3Node = document.getElementsByTagName("h3")[0];
        h3Node.innerHTML = "17." + h3Node.innerHTML
    });

</script>
```

## Bonus

If you have multiple such `<h3>` tags and you want to dynamically add section number according to their corresponding position take a look at following example

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <h3>
            如何查询我购买的订单？
        </h3>
        <p>您好，请微信关注“中通创客”，点击右下角“我的”，选择“订单查询”查询订单信息。
        </p>
    </div>
    <div>
        <h3>
            如何查询我购买的订单？
        </h3>
        <p>您好，请微信关注“中通创客”，点击右下角“我的”，选择“订单查询”查询订单信息。
        </p>
    </div>
    <div>
        <h3>
            如何查询我购买的订单？
        </h3>
        <p>您好，请微信关注“中通创客”，点击右下角“我的”，选择“订单查询”查询订单信息。
        </p>
    </div>
    <div>
        <h3>
            如何查询我购买的订单？
        </h3>
        <p>您好，请微信关注“中通创客”，点击右下角“我的”，选择“订单查询”查询订单信息。
        </p>
    </div>
    <div>
        <h3>
            如何查询我购买的订单？
        </h3>
        <p>您好，请微信关注“中通创客”，点击右下角“我的”，选择“订单查询”查询订单信息。
        </p>
    </div>
    <div>
        <h3>
            如何查询我购买的订单？
        </h3>
        <p>您好，请微信关注“中通创客”，点击右下角“我的”，选择“订单查询”查询订单信息。
        </p>
    </div>
    <div>
        <h3>
            如何查询我购买的订单？
        </h3>
        <p>您好，请微信关注“中通创客”，点击右下角“我的”，选择“订单查询”查询订单信息。
        </p>
    </div>
    <div>
        <h3>
            如何查询我购买的订单？
        </h3>
        <p>您好，请微信关注“中通创客”，点击右下角“我的”，选择“订单查询”查询订单信息。
        </p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>

<script>
    window.addEventListener("load", function () {    
        var h3Nodes = document.getElementsByTagName("h3");
        for (var index = 0; index < h3Nodes.length; index++) {
            var h3Node = h3Nodes[index];
            h3Node.innerHTML = (index+1) + "." + h3Node.innerHTML;
        }
    });

</script>
```