# Dynamically added stylesheet only taken into account if first one

Tags: javascript, css, macos, cocoa, wkwebview

I am adding dynamically 2 style sheets in a `WKWebView` having local content loaded using `loadFileURL`.

The cocoa application calls the following javascript snippet to add the stylesheets.

```
var link = document.createElement('link');
link.setAttribute('rel', 'stylesheet');
link.type = 'text/css';
link.title = csstype;
link.href = cssSheetPath1;
document.head.appendChild(link);

var link = document.createElement('link');
link.setAttribute('rel', 'stylesheet');
link.type = 'text/css';
link.title = csstype;
link.href = cssSheetPath2;
document.head.appendChild(link);
```

The 2 stylesheets are located in the same directory. I can either load the first one or the second one, but never both. If I try to load both, only the first one is applied.

Any idea from where the issue can come from?

Answer (score 1):

You have to run that twice. Make a function and then call it for both stylesheets.

```js
const createLink = (cssSheetPath) => {
    const link = document.createElement('link');
    link.setAttribute('rel', 'stylesheet');
    link.type = 'text/css';
    link.href = cssSheetPath;
    document.head.appendChild(link);
}

createLink('style1.css');
createLink('style2.css');
```

---

added a running code example: [codesandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/s/rrwx1wx1kn?fontsize=14&module=%2Fsrc%2Findex.js)

---

If you dont use a function, then you should try to use two different var names:

```js
var link = document.createElement('link');
link.setAttribute('rel', 'stylesheet');
link.type = 'text/css';
link.title = csstype;
link.href = cssSheetPath1;
document.head.appendChild(link);

var link1 = document.createElement('link');
link1.setAttribute('rel', 'stylesheet');
link1.type = 'text/css';
link1.title = csstype;
link1.href = cssSheetPath2;
document.head.appendChild(link1);
```

I can't test it with WKWebView.

Comment: This is exactly what I am doing and what is not working hence my question.

Comment: you define only one link element in your example. So, you overwrite it, when you try to use this element for two stylesheets.

Comment: Thanks, I know that it works in a browser. My issue is with the WKWebView where it only one for the first one. (If I swap them, as well)

Comment: issue remains the same

Comment: i found this -> [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33126467/10921798). Maybe it helps.