# Disable WKWebView longpress actionsheet only for links

Tags: javascript, ios, swift, wkwebview, mobile-webkit

This solution, found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26460417/disable-wkactionsheet-on-wkwebview), does work for disabling the action sheet all together but I'd like to disable it only for links or anchor tags and leave it working for images so I don't have to recreate that native functionality.

```
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
    webView.evaluateJavaScript("document.body.style.webkitTouchCallout='none';", completionHandler: nil)
}
```

I'm not great with javascript but for someone who is I imagine this is trivial.

I've tried hobbling together something using the same `webkitTouchCallout` but it isn't working for me. It doesn't produce any errors, it just doesn't disable the actionsheet at all.

```
webView.evaluateJavaScript("var anchors = document.anchors; var array = Array.prototype.slice.call( anchors, 0 ); array.forEach(function(anchor) { anchor.style.webkitTouchCallout='none'; });", completionHandler: { result, error in
    print("Javascript didFinish Error: \(error)")
})
```